# Есть ли функция, возвращающая дробную часть после деления двух вещественных чисел

Tags: python, numpy

Например 6/5 = 1,2.  Мне нужно получить именно 0,2.
Я конечно написал нужную функцию:

```
def rest(a, b):
    if a < b:
        return a/b
    if a == b:
        return 0.0
    else:   # a>b
        return  a/b - int(a/b)
```

но может есть такая функция где-то, скажем, в numpy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```py
import math

frac, whole = math.modf(1.2)
print(frac)
print(whole)
```

Другой способ:

```py
frac = 1.2 % 1
print(frac)
```